# Pass property into root component of Vue 3 app from main.ts

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-props

I try to pass a boolean property to App.vue from inside main.ts

main.ts:

```js
const freshchatActive = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  vuetify,
  props: { freshchatActive: Boolean },
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

App.Vue:

```js
export default class App extends Vue {
  @Prop({ default: () => false }) freshchatActive!: boolean;

  created() {
    console.log("created #freshchatActive", this.freshchatActive);
  }
```

However, the console always prints the default value (false).
How would I pass in the property when creating the application root component in main.ts?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Kind Regards
Stephan

Comment: i don't know if that is possible that way, but if you explain what you want to achieve, we may help you find an alternative solution

Comment: The problem is, that you mix Vue 3 and Vue 2 here. You need to use `createApp` in vue 3

Comment: When using `createApp` you can pass root properties as second parameter to the function: https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#createapp

Comment: @LeifMarcus Thank you, this is an existing application that I took over in maintenance. Interesting to learn that it might be a mix of Vue 2 and Vue 3. So, from your comment I gather that `new Vue(...).$mount("#app")` is Vue 2 and there is no way to pass properties to the root component in Vue 2? Thank you for the link to the documentation of `createApp`. This explains it quite well.

Comment: Yes, `new Vue(…)` is like Vue 2. But in Vue 2 there is also a way to add properties: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering. See also the vue migration guide: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#global-api-application-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the render function, you need to pass the props to the `h` function like

```js
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  vuetify,
  render: h => 
    h(App, { 
      freshchatActive: true 
    }),
}).$mount("#app");
```

Just to clarify, the way the app is initialized is not Vue 3 as mentioned in my comments.